# How to retrieve the previous record in navision

Tags: dynamics-nav, navision

I'm new to navision, and I need need to retrieve the previous record from a table because I need its records. 
So my question is : how can I retrieve the record that's just before the one I'm working with?

explanation : 
I'm seaching but can't really find what I need on google. I actually can't use .GET() as one of the fields in the primary key varies from record to record.
what I need to do is calculate the difference in a field form a record and the previous e.g :

curent record : total : 150
previous : total : 100

what I need to do is to retrieve the total of the previous record in order to store the difference in another record.
current record : difference : 50

Comment: Make sure you post the code you already have. As suggested below, Rec.Next(-1) will move the current record one position back. This might interfere with your programming, so you have to show what you're doing if you need specific help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[NEXT(-1)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd301233.aspx)

Are you banned by google and microsoft simultaneously?

Comment: I'm seaching but can't really find what I need. I actually can't use get as one of the fields in the primary key varies from record to record.

Comment: `next(-1)` is what you looking for as I said